# Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, feature-selection

I am getting this error:

> ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given
>   (type ): Index(['CreditScore',
>   'Age', 'Tenure', 'Balance', 'NumOfProducts', 'HasCrCard',
>          'IsActiveMember', 'EstimatedSalary', 'Exited'],
>         dtype='object').

I am using tensorFlow lib. I want to get prediction results but I can not run `m.train(input_fn=get_input_fn ,steps=5000)` code. I always got the same error whatever I did. I used these  input functions in the following but nothing changed.

```
def input_fn_train():
     x=tf.constant(df_train.astype(np.float64)),
     y=tf.constant(df_train[LABEL].astype(np.float64))
     return x, y
```

and

```
def get_input_fn(data_set, num_epochs=None, shuffle=False):
     return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
      x=pd.DataFrame({k: data_set[k].values for k in data_set.columns}),
      y=pd.Series(data_set[LABEL].values), num_epochs=num_epochs,
                  shuffle=shuffle)
```

I can not understand what should I do. What the error is about? I've been googling but never found useful thing. How can I handle this error. The code is below. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tempfile

COLS= ["RowNumber","CustomerId","Surname","CreditScore","Geography",
"Gender","Age","Tenure","Balance","NumOfProducts","HasCrCard",
"IsActiveMember","EstimatedSalary","Exited"]


FEATURES = ["CreditScore","Age","Tenure","Balance","NumOfProducts",
       "HasCrCard","IsActiveMember", "EstimatedSalary"]

LABEL="Exited"

df_train = pd.read_csv("Churn_Modelling.csv", skipinitialspace=True, 
header=0)
df_test = pd.read_csv("Churn_Modelling.csv", skipinitialspace=True, 
header=0)
test_label = df_test[LABEL].astype(float)
df_test.drop("Surname", axis = 1, inplace=True)
df_test.drop("RowNumber", axis = 1, inplace=True)
df_test.drop("CustomerId", axis = 1, inplace=True)
df_train.drop("CustomerId", axis = 1, inplace=True)
df_train.drop("Surname", axis = 1, inplace=True)
df_train.drop("RowNumber", axis = 1, inplace=True)
df_train.drop("Geography", axis = 1, inplace=True)
df_train.drop("Gender", axis = 1, inplace=True)

def get_input_fn():
    return {'x': tf.constant(df_train[FEATURES].as_matrix(), tf.float32, 
           df_train.shape),
           'y': tf.constant(df_train[LABEL].as_matrix(), tf.float32, 
            df_train.shape)
           }

 df=df_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
 numeric_cols=df.columns

 m = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(model_dir=model_dir, feature_columns=
[numeric_cols])

 m.train(input_fn=get_input_fn ,steps=5000)
 results = m.evaluate(input_fn= get_input_fn(df_test, num_epochs=1, 
 shuffle=False),steps=None)

 y = m.predict(input_fn=get_input_fn(df_test, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False))
 pred = list(y)

 rowNumber=0
 for i in pred:
     print(str(rowNumber)+': '+str(pred[i]))
     rowNumber=rowNumber+1
```

Comment: I guess you are uploading a common file but dropping different columns from training and testing set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working clearly.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tempfile
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score


def split_data(data, rate, label):
    data = data.dropna()

    train_data, test_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=rate)

    train_label = train_data[label]
    train_data = train_data.drop(label, 1)

    test_label = test_data[label]
    test_data = test_data.drop(label, 1)
    return train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label



LABEL = "Exited"

data = pd.read_csv("Churn_Modelling.csv", skipinitialspace=True, 
    header=0)

data.drop("Surname", axis=1, inplace=True)
data.drop("RowNumber", axis=1, inplace=True)
data.drop("CustomerId", axis=1, inplace=True)
data.drop("Geography", axis=1, inplace=True)
data.drop("Gender", axis=1, inplace=True)
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = split_data(data, 0.20, LABEL)



def get_input_fn_train():
    input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=x_train,
        y=y_train,
        shuffle=False
    )
    return input_fn

def get_input_fn_test():
    input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=x_test,
        y=y_test,
        shuffle=False
    )
    return input_fn


feature_columns = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input_fn
(get_input_fn_train())


model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(model_dir=model_dir, 
feature_columns=feature_columns)

# train data
m.train(input_fn=get_input_fn_train(), steps=5000)

# you can get accuracy, accuracy_baseline, auc, auc_precision_recall, 
#average_loss, global_step, label/mean, lossprediction/mean

results = m.evaluate(input_fn=get_input_fn_test(), steps=None)

print("model directory = %s" % model_dir)
for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))

# get prediction results
y = m.predict(input_fn=get_input_fn_test())
predictions = list(y)
pred1=pd.DataFrame(data=predictions)
prediction=pd.DataFrame(data=pred1['class_ids'])
pred=[]
for row in prediction["class_ids"]:
    pred.append(row[0])

rowNumber = 0
for i in pred:
    print(str(rowNumber) + ': ' + str(i))
    rowNumber = rowNumber + 1


def calculate(prediction, LABEL):
    arr = {"accuracy": accuracy_score(prediction, LABEL),
           "report": classification_report(prediction, LABEL),
           "Confusion_Matrix": confusion_matrix(prediction, LABEL),
           "F1 score": f1_score(prediction, LABEL),
           "Recall Score": recall_score(prediction, LABEL),
           "cohen_kappa": cohen_kappa_score(prediction, LABEL)
           }
    return arr


pred2 = pd.DataFrame(data=pred)

print(calculate(pred2.round(), y_test))
```

Answer (score 6):

Your first mistake is how you create `tf.estimator.LinearClassifier`. You're passing the dataframe index `df.columns` into `feature_columns`, but should pass the list of [tensorflow feature columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column). The columns should define if it's numerical or categorical and in the later case the encoding type.

Secondly, the input function can be simplified a lot, since you're reading `pandas` dataframe. Just use `tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn`.

Your `.csv` is most likely different, I've made a dummy one with some values. So here's a way to read the input and fit the model correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

FEATURES = ["CreditScore", "Age", "Tenure", "Balance", "NumOfProducts", 
            "HasCrCard", "IsActiveMember", "EstimatedSalary", "Exited"]

credit_score = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("CreditScore")
age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Age")
tenure = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Tenure")
balance = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Balance")
num_of_products = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("NumOfProducts")
has_card = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("HasCrCard", ["True", "False"])
is_active_member = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("IsActiveMember", ["True", "False"])
estimated_salary = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("EstimatedSalary")
feature_columns = [credit_score, age, tenure, balance, num_of_products, has_card, is_active_member, estimated_salary]

def input_fn(num_epochs=None, shuffle=True, batch_size=100):
  df = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv',
                   names=FEATURES,
                   dtype={'HasCrCard': str, 'IsActiveMember': str},
                   skipinitialspace=True,
                   header=0)
  df = df.dropna(how='any', axis=0)   # remove NaN elements
  labels = df["Exited"]
  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=df,
                                             y=labels,
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             num_epochs=num_epochs,
                                             shuffle=shuffle,
                                             num_threads=5)

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(model_dir=None,
                                      feature_columns=feature_columns)
model.train(input_fn=input_fn(), steps=100)
```

Comment: It is not working this code I am getting error . "SystemError: <built-in function TF_Run> returned a result with an error set"  It was about feature columns we recreate feature_columns=tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input_fn(get_input_fn_train())

Comment: This code is working. Like I said, your `.csv` is probably different. Since you didn't describe what columns and types you have, I created a simple csv, where all columns are numeric, except for two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some small changes to @Maxim's answer (thanks, btw) and post a minimum working example with random numpy data. This seems to run fine on my windows machine. Note the [suppressed warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u) due to my particular hardware.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

FEATURES = ["CreditScore", "Age", "Tenure", "Balance", "NumOfProducts", "EstimatedSalary", "Exited"]
credit_score = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("CreditScore")
age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Age")
tenure = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Tenure")
balance = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Balance")
num_of_products = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("NumOfProducts")
estimated_salary = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("EstimatedSalary")
feature_columns = [credit_score, age, tenure, balance, num_of_products, estimated_salary]

def input_fn(num_epochs=None, shuffle=True, batch_size=100):
  N_features = len(FEATURES)
  print(N_features)
  N_examples = 5000
  X_train = np.random.rand(N_examples,N_features)
  Y_train  = np.random.rand(N_examples)
  columns = [str(i) for i in range(N_features)]
  columns = FEATURES
  df = pd.DataFrame(data = X_train, columns = columns)
  labels = df["Exited"]
  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=df,
                                             y=labels,
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             num_epochs=num_epochs,
                                             shuffle=shuffle,
                                             num_threads=5)

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(model_dir='model_dir',
                                      feature_columns=feature_columns)
model.train(input_fn=input_fn(), steps=100)
```