# tf.Session() freeze in pix2pix code (CPU mode)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get the hidden layers values (and create PNG images) in `create_generator` function in [pix2pix.py](https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow/blob/master/pix2pix.py) code.
I've added those lines (in `create_generator` function):

```
layer_8 = tf.image.encode_png(tf.cast((tf.reshape(layers[-1], [256, 256, 3]) + 1.) * 127.5, tf.uint8))
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        png_data_ = sess.run(layer_8)
        open("test_images/temp.png", 'wb').write(png_data_)
```

I run in Test mode. when I'm running it I see this warning:

```
2017-11-09 10:23:31.897014: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
```

and the program does not continue to run. I'm working with CPU (without GPU). what am I doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u