# Tensorflow install fails with "compiletime version 3.5 of module does not match runtime version 3.6"

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I tried installing from pip:

```
pip3 install --user --no-cache https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Then tried importing and got:

```
 Using TensorFlow backend.
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:205: RuntimeWarning: 
  compiletime version 3.5 of module 
  'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime 
  version 3.6
    return f(*args, **kwds)

  2017-11-10 09:35:01.206112: I 
  tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports 
  instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 
  SSE4.2 AVX
```

Questions:

1. I don't understand why the wheel says 3.6, but I get the warning about 3.5
2. I want to compile to optimize for my cpu, so can I use pip to install from source rather than from binary wheel?

Comment: Post the result of the `arch` command in a shell. It most likely isn't `x86_64`.

Comment: yes, arch says x86_64, that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 17):

> RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14182), which is got [prioritized](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14182#issuecomment-342927115) and likely to be fixed soon. Right now the workaround is to use python 3.5.

**UPDATE:**

The issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14182#issuecomment-349784085) in the nightly tensorflow builds: *"`tf-nightly` and `tf-nightly-gpu` now has a python3.6 binary built from scratch for Linux."*

I.e., the following command should work with python 3.6:

```
# tf-nightly or tf-nightly-gpu
pip3 install tf-nightly
```

> Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX

This warning comes from the fact that the default tensorflow distributions are compiled *without CPU extensions* support (more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47068709/712995)). If you want to get a CPU optimized tensorflow package, your only option is to [build it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41293077/712995). It's a bit tedious, but absolutely doable. The build will produce the wheel file, which you can install with just

```
pip3 install /path/to/the/tensorflow.whl
```

But if you just want to suppress the warning, this will do:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Comment: So, is this warning non-harmful, so that we can afford to suppress it? And if yes, is there any way to permanently suppress it instead of doing `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'` every time I want to use tensorflow?

Comment: @Kristada673 Yes, it's mentioned in this answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227886/712995 Do `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2` from the command line

Comment: I was referring to the warning `RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6`. When I do `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2`, this warning does not go away. Is it non-harmful? If yes, how can I ignore it? And if no, how can I fix it?

Comment: @Kristada673 I see. No, this warning won't go away that easily. It seems not break tf, but certain internal packages won't import, you never know which function may fail. All currently available fixes are in the answer

Answer (score 7):

I got the same issue and I was able to solve it by installing 1.3 version rather than using 1.4 of tensorflow. Use the following command to do so.

```
 pip3 install tensorflow==1.3.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem and I fixed it by:

```
pip install --ignore-installed tensorflow
```

The problem occurred because I complied a local version of tensorflow (to enable some CPU features) with python 3.5 earlier.  I installed python 3.6 recently and the new tensorlfow already supported those CPU features, so I just installed the official version.

**Update**:

After some update of `tensorflow` the approach above doesn't work any more.

Another workaround is using virtual environment such as [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) to create a python3.5 environment:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
source activate py35
pip install tensorflow
```

To work with ipython or jupyter notebook, be sure to install ipykernel inside the virtual environment:

```
pip install ipykernel
```

Answer (score 4):

Just install 1.3 version of tensorflow. Problem solved.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**solution 1.**
the way I solved this is by downgrading to the latest python3.5, go to python.org download the latest Python3.5, install it and then use normal`pip3 install tensorflow` this should be able to fix the issue if not try the second solution.

**solution 2(also you need to downgrade from python3.6 to python3.5** 
I used [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) to solve the issue, I created a project inside the pycharm editor then I changed the Project Interpreter from python3.6 to python3.5, to do this as well go to File > Preferences  search for Project Interpreter, and from the drop-down menu change from python3.6 to python3.5 
hit Apply wait for the operation to finish

[image]
and then in the same window using the **+** icon

[image]

A window will appear that will let you search and install python libraries easily without using pip, in our case we want tensorflow, so just search tensorflow, select tensorflow on search result and click Install Package this will install the package

[image]

and voila you're ready to roll, now you got tensorflow installed on your python3.5, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

For now you can use python version less than  3.6.x because now Tensorflow 1.4.0 is not working properly with python 3.6.x. It will surly work.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved on ubuntu 17.10 by running

`$ conda install tensorflow`

Comment: I also found that by installing a virtual environment with python 3.6.3 then activating the environment before installing tensorflow, the issue was resolved.



`$conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6.3 Anaconda --y`
`$conda update conda`
`$source activate envname`
`$conda install tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

i use tensorflow 1.4.0, meet the same problem. but you can use tensorflow 1.6.0, now.