# TensorFlow warnings with Python

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

running on Mac osX 10.13.2 , installed the cpu version of tensorflow

1. I installed tensorflow v1.4 and I'm getting this mismatch warning.  luckily it  executes but I don't know how to get tensorflow that matches Python 3.6 ??
2. I did the test to validate my installation and it's also a little odd. the print command doesn't look like it really executed.  there is b ' ... '
   ( see below )
3. some note about instructions that my cpu supports that tensorflow binary does not.

I'm new at this ,  so thanks..

**Testing tensorflow in the terminal window on MacBook :**

```
Last login: Tue Dec 12 11:36:14 on ttys000
fredericks-MBP:~ bravo$ python
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Sep 21 2017, 18:29:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import tensorflow as tf
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:205: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

=========================
validate installation :

```
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2017-12-12 11:48:30.408157: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
>>> 
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow install fails with "compiletime version 3.5 of module does not match runtime version 3.6"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225210/tensorflow-install-fails-with-compiletime-version-3-5-of-module-does-not-match)

Answer (score 0):

The b'...' regarding your point 2 is not a problem. The answer you are getting is a python bytes literals instead of a string, thus the b in front of it. See [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)