# cannot fine-tune a Keras model with 4 VGG16

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I build a model with 4 VGG16 (not including the top) and then concatenate the 4 outputs from the 4 VGG16 to form a dense layer, which is followed by a softmax layer, so my model has 4 inputs (4 images) and 1 output (4 classes).

I first do the transfer learning by just training the dense layers and freezing the layers from VGG16, and that works fine.

However, after unfreeze the VGG16 layers by setting `layer.trainable = True`, I get the following errors:

`tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018 23:12:28.501894: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX TITAN X major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.076
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0
totalMemory: 11.93GiB freeMemory: 11.71GiB
2018 23:12:28.744990: I`
`tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:444] could not convert BatchDescriptor {count: 0 feature_map_count: 512 spatial: 14 14 value_min: 0.000000 value_max: 0.000000 layout: BatchDepthYX} to cudnn tensor descriptor: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM`

Then I follow the solution in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u) and set `os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'`. The first error above is gone, but I still get the second error:

`keras tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:444 could not convert BatchDescriptor  to cudnn tensor descriptor: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM`

If I freeze the VGG16 layers again, then the code works fine. In other works, those errors only occur when I set the VGG16 layers trainable.

I also build a model with only 1 VGG16, and that model also works fine.

So, in summary, only when I unfreeze the VGG16 layers in a model with 4 VGG16, I get those errors.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it has nothing to do the number of VGG16 in the model. The problem is due to the batch size.

When I said the model with 1 VGG16 worked, that model used batch size 8. And when I reduced the batch size smaller than 4 (either 1, 2, or 3), then the same errors happened.

Now I just use batch size 4 for the model with 4 VGG16, and it works fine, although I still don't know why it fails when batch size < 4 (probably it's related to the fact I'm using 4 GPUs).