# InvalidArgumentError when using TPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to TPU and I encounter an error when I try to train a CNN (on TPU) on my own dataset. I am able to run MNIST example and run my code when `--use_tpu=False`. But when I set `--use_tpu=Ture`, I will have

> InvalidArgumentError

.

**I System**
The tf-1-7 image, as mentioned in the tutorial.

**II Error**

> 2018-04-17 06:35:31.602915: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   FMA   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1327, in _do_call return fn(*args)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1310, in _run_fn self._extend_graph()   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1358, in _extend_graph graph_def.SerializeToString(), status)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py",
>   line 516, in exit c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot
>   assign a device for operation
>   'input_pipeline_task0/IteratorToStringHandle': Operation was
>   explicitly assigned to /job:tpu_worker/task:0/device:CPU:0 but
>   available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
>   ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
>   [[Node: input_pipeline_task0/IteratorToStringHandle =
>   IteratorToStringHandle_device="/job:tpu_worker/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

My thought is that it is caused by the way I input the data. Now, I use pickle to load the data in the local machine and then use from_tensor_slices to import data. I tried to save data in google cloud storage but it will report "the file cannot be found."

Any solutions? Or better way to import data?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure if you have set ‘use_tpu’ to ‘True’ instead of ‘Ture’. As for the [AVX2 CPU instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u#answer-47227886), newer CPUs uses these instructions but work for TPUs do not need these instructions as most of the work will be done in TPUs and using standard instructions for CPUs will allow compatibility with older generation CPUs.

As for using the [Cloud Storage for TPUs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/storage-buckets), make sure your Cloud Storage bucket and Cloud TPU are in the same zone. Currently TPUs are available in ‘us-central1-b’ and ‘us-central1-c’, so choose the same location for Cloud Storage.