# pickle Keras ANN

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, pickle

I am trying to use this code to fit an ANN using Keras and then pickle it:

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, mode='auto')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=40, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', activation='sigmoid', W_regularizer=reg))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks=[early_stopping])

pickle_file_and_path = 'C:/Bla/DLModel20180816.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(pickle_file_and_path, 'wb'))
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
  pickle.dump(model, open(pickle_file_and_path, 'wb'))
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to pickle the model instead of using the built-in `model.save()` to store is as a `.h5`?

Comment: Thanks. TBH I was not aware of this. As long as I can persist it and then read in via another script. Could you please be so kind and suggest some code to write and read a 'Keras model' you way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way of storing Keras models is to use the built-in `model.save()` method which will save the model into a HDF5 file.

Adapting your code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=40, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', input_dim=x_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', activation='sigmoid', W_regularizer=reg))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Save the model
model.save('./model.h5')
```

Afterwards, you can load it as follows:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('./model.h5')
```

And start retraining or use the model for inference. Note that you can also store the only the weights with the `save_weights()` method. For the full documentation and more examples see the Keras [website](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

Comment: could it be that you miss load_model?

Comment: Also I am getting: Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 )-:

Comment: You can safely ignore that. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u) is some explanation on what it means.

Comment: I also came across this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/ It saves structure and weights separably though?