# TensorFlow session fails with error not compiled to use AVX2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

My tensorflow session ran into an error which indicates that the installation on Windows (CPU only support) does not support AVX2. Any ideas?

```
    sess = tf.Session()
    2018-08-20 00:52:18.807532: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message doesn't indicate error.

It is just an information message that says that your version of Tensorflow doesn't use some instructions (AVX) that are supported by the CPU.

It means that you can get better performance if you rebuild Tensorflow with enabled support for those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that your CPU doesn't support AVX. Just try the below one.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Please find the detailed answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u)

Comment: Actually it means the opposite