# How can I install the latest version of tensorflow?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, installation

I want to install the latest version of tensorflow (1.12.0) in my machine and installed it using `pip install tensorflow`. The 1.12.0 version of the tensorflow installed  in my linux machine without any error but when I tried to import tensorflow in my python shell its giving this error and aborting the tensorflow import.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine. 
Aborted
```

In this answer it is said that its a [simple warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227886/996366) but mine is not a warning its aborting the import of tensorflow completely. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow multiple times but the same problem persists. I then tried to install the lowest version of tensorflow `pip install tensorflow==1.0.0` this works and able to to install an older version of tensorflow.

How can I install the latest version of tensorflow?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Comment: @jww If it was some ordinary software installation I would not have posted this question here but its releated to a programming enviroment causing troubles to programers. Should I change the title lets say `Abort error: The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine` will that make this question suitable for his SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem your CPU doesn't not support AVX instructions.

Since version 1.6 use AVX instructions, thus TF cannot be used on "old" CPUs.

However there is some unofficial built. But you will probably not find built on latest version of tensorflow.

Here is a thread about it : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18689

Comment: Just an info: The solution to this problem is `installing tensorflow version less than 1.6` else `build from the source`