# conda install Tensorflow 2.1 with mkl (avx/avx2 support) not working

Tags: tensorflow, installation, anaconda, avx, avx2

I was using tensorflow 2.0 with mkl (avx/avx2 optimization) and has zero problem. I found yesterday that tf 2.1 is available on anaconda, so I upgrade it to the latest. however, after upgrade, tf complains that "Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2".

To make sure I installed the correct version. I uninstalled all tensorflow components, and then do a fresh install using command conda install tensorflow-mkl. The installation succeed but the problem persists.

Could anyone advise how to solve this? Very appreciate the help.

Best

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tensorflow warn about AVX2 while I am using MKL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979991/why-does-tensorflow-warn-about-avx2-while-i-am-using-mkl)

Comment: I am not sure if this warning can be ignored. With tf 2.0, there is no such warning. with tf 2.1,  the performance is worse compared to 2.0 when running the same training script.