# TensorFlow binary was not compiled

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, gpu, ubuntu-14.04

I am running this code in [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/video-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/).

The output:

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

[INFO] approx. FPS: 10, assume reach to 30
```

Why is the code is running on the CPU?

I have a GPU, and I installed TensorFlow using `tensorflow-gpu`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a GPU, you should not care about it. You can ignore the warning using this

```py
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
```

If you want more information about it, you can read:

- A similar post: [Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u)
- A similar issue on github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7778

Comment: thank you so much for this information, but when I used the line : 'sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))'  , the output: 'Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 -> device: XLA_CPU device'