# Installing TensorFlow binaries supporting AVX, FMA, SSE for Python 3.6 and TF 1.12..0

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, cpu, bazel

I would like to install the TF version supporting the correct CPU extension to improve performance.

Following [this instruntion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u) and [this](https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build) repo, I cannot find a matching distribution supporting Python 3.6 and TF 10.12.0

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since you have used the `bazel` tag, I assume you have tried building Tensorflow from the sources ? If you did, what where your parameters for the `bazel build` command ? If not, I would suggest you follow [this official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a build on the external links that should satisfy all your requirements [here](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues/95). From the very repo you linked, in the **External Links** sections, is listed that build with support for TF 1.12.0, CPU, MacOS Mojave, Python 3.6.0, FMA, AVX, AVX2, SSE4.1, SSE4.2.

If that doesn't work for you for some reason, more info would be needed. In that case however, since that's the only build on there that resembles what you asked, a complete build with bazel will probably be necessary. For the specific flags in the `bazel build` however, if you can't afford to use the default `-march=native`, which will optimize for all the flags available on your CPU, you may want to check out what specific flags you need from the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html).