# Tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow to do sentiment analysis using python and this error happens

2019-06-08 17:08:06.104566: IT:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\                                                                                                                                   cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow bi                                                                                                                                 nary was not compiled to use: AVX2

Comment: what is your tf version?

Comment: Did this previous SO answer not work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u