# IndexError in py_call_impl

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am a master student, currently enrolled in an R project course. While setting up a deep learning model, I came across some issues. I would appreciate if somebody could help me. I reinstalled R, RStudio, Python, Anaconda, but couldn't resolve the issue.

```
library (keras);library(tensorflow);
install_tensorflow(); install_keras()
library(ggplot2); library(magrittr);
library(dplyr); library(tm); library(tidyr); 



clothing_reviews <- read.csv("C:/Users/Astrid/Documents/Master BWL/Data Mining mit R/R/Präsentation 2/Womens Clothing Reviews.csv") %>%
+   mutate(Liked = ifelse(Rating == 5, 1, 0),
+          text = paste("Title", "Review.Text"),
+          text = gsub("NA", "", text))
> 

> glimpse(clothing_reviews)
Observations: 28,222
Variables: 13
$ X                             <fct> "0", "1,1080,34,,\"Love this dress!  it's sooo pretty.  i happened to fi...
$ Clothing.ID                   <fct> 767, , , , 847, , , , 1077, , 1077, 1095, , ,  so i would say it's runni...
$ Age                           <fct> 33, , , , 47, , , , 24, , 53, 39, , , , , , 50, , , 41, , , , , , , , , ...
$ Title                         <fct> , , , , Flattering shirt, , , , Flattering, , Dress looks like it's made...
$ Review.Text                   <fct> Absolutely wonderful - silky and sexy and comfortable, , , , This shirt ...
$ Rating                        <fct> 4, , , , 5, , , , 5, , 3, 5, , , , , , 3, , , 5, , , , , , , , , , , , ,...
$ Recommended.IND               <fct> 1, , , , 1, , , , 1, , 0, 1, , , , , , 1, , , 1, , , , , , , , , , , , ,...
$ Positive.Feedback.Count       <fct> 0, , , , 6, , , , 0, , 14, 2, , , , , , 1, , , 0, , , , , , , , , , , , ...
$ Division.Name                 <fct> Initmates, , , , General, , , , General, , General, General Petite, , , ...
$ Department.Name               <fct> Intimate, , , , Tops, , , , Dresses, , Dresses, Dresses, , , , , , Dress...
$ Class.Name................... <fct> Intimates;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;, , , , Blouses;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;, , , , Dr...
$ Liked                         <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ text                          <chr> "Title Review.Text", "Title Review.Text", "Title Review.Text", "Title Re...
> 

> clothing_reviews %>%
+   ggplot(aes(x = factor(Liked), fill = Liked)) +
+   geom_bar(alpha = 0.8) + 
+   guides(fill = FALSE)
> 

> reviews_total<-rbind(clothing_reviews$Liked,
+                      clothing_reviews$text)
> 

> reviews_m<-as.matrix(reviews_total)
> dimnames(reviews_m)<-NULL
> 
> set.seed(123)
> ind<-sample(2,nrow(reviews_m),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))
> reviews_train<-reviews_m[ind==1,1]
> reviews_test<-reviews_m[ind==2,1]
> reviews_trainlabel<-as.numeric(reviews_m[ind==1,2])
> reviews_testlabel<-as.numeric(reviews_m[ind==2,2])
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> 
> maxlen<-100
> max_words<-10000
> tokenizer<-text_tokenizer(num_words=max_words)%>%
+   fit_text_tokenizer(reviews_train)
> sequences<-texts_to_sequences(tokenizer, reviews_train)
> word_index= tokenizer$word_index
> 

> x_train<-pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=maxlen)
> y_train<-as.array(reviews_trainlabel)
> 
> batch_size <- 20
> epochs <- 12
> 
> model <- keras_model_sequential()%>%
+   layer_embedding(input_dim = max_words, output_dim = 100)%>%
+   layer_lstm(units = 16)%>%
+   layer_dense(1)%>%
+   layer_activation("sigmoid")%>% compile(
+     loss = "binary_crossentropy",
+     optimizer = "adam",
+     metrics = "accuracy"
+     
+   )
> 
> hist <- model %>%
+   fit(
+     x_train,
+     y_train,
+     batch_size = batch_size,
+     epochs = epochs,
+     validation_split = 0.3
+   )
```

> 2019-07-21 20:19:34.543600: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>
> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>     IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: re the first message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u . The second error seems more important ... sorry I cant help ... bt it may be worth changing your title to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the first 'error' is just an indication, that the TensorFlow binary you installed is not 'optimal' for your CPU. Instead of installing the default TensorFlow you can build form source and thus optimize the CPU usage etc., but this is not an error (when I'm working with Tensorflow / Keras I get this too.)

Further for the second error, a quick search showed: https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/238#issuecomment-383189626
where it is discussed that it seems that the `py_call_imb()` error happens due to dependencies related to RStudio / Keras.

To quote from another [answer](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/238#issuecomment-383272059), apparently one user could resolve the issue:

"Well - I used https://mran.microsoft.com/package/keras, where version 2.1.5, published 2018-03-25 is announced. However, upon installing as indicated, the whole process as described in my last post starts again. (I just repeated it, alas...). Only from devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras") I am able to get a working installation."

Comment: Thank you for your help GrizZ. I followed your suggestion, but the error message is still there. Could there be a problem due to the version of a program? I use R 3.6.1, RStudio 1.2.1335, Rtools 3.5, Anacona 2.7, python 3.6.8.

Comment: Thank you for help GrizZ. I followed your suggestion but the error message is still there. Could there be a problem with any version of a program? I use R 3.6.1, Rtools 3.5, RStudio 1.2.1335 , python 3.6.8, Anaconda 2.7, keras_2.2.4.1.9001, tensorflow_1.13.1.

Comment: @As123 https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/693#issuecomment-470892009 please try downgrading to tensorflow 1.12: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/693#issuecomment-470892009 whereas it seems to be about incompatible versions.

Comment: Thank you @GrizZ the error disappeared. But now I received the error message that my training set has 0 samples. How can I fix the error: AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values' ?

Comment: @As123 please make a new question for the 'ProgbarLogger' issue as the current question is resolved. This is better than to discuss different problems in the comment section :)