# Why my TensorFlow Serving using bazel build copt avx2 doesn't help to speed up the inference?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I'm build my tf-serving service with tensorflow-v1.12.0. I've tried all kinds of copt available for my CPU. But the result failed my expectation. The picture below shows the performances for each copt in my project.
[image: performances for each copt]

I was wondering why the copt doesn't make any positive difference.
reference: [Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u)

Answer (score 0):

Finally find it out by myself. It's because that I didn't enable mkl in compilation. The correct way to compile your TF with CPU instructions set optimization is to add "--config=mkl -c opt --copt=mavx2"

It reduce about 20% of predict time cost in my project.