# Issues with flask in Windows PowerShell

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use Windows PowerShell to install flask but when I execute `python app.py` I get this error

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\flask\Deployed Model> python app.py
```

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   2020-06-01 12:36:45.548048: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   Model loaded. Start serving...

Can anyone help me with this error? I installed all the libraries in Windows PowerShell and I also installed tensorflow==2.0

Comment: It's running isn't it? That's just a warning that you could be using features to speed things up. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment I'm writing this answer instead.
It seems like you don't have a GPU installed on your PC and if its true then you need to compile tensorflow binary for use.

This warning is specific to your CPU and it tells that your CPU dosen't support AVX2.

But if you have a GPU then simply disable the warning using

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```