# How to rebuild tensorflow with the compiler flags?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run binary classification with a tensorflow backend but I keep receiving an error that I believe asks me to rebuild tensorflow with the right compiler flags. I know that my code and data is functionally, so I think the problem is with virtual environment. I have tried finding solutions on tensorflow's website, ibm's website, and stack overflow, but I haven't been successful. I have also tried reinstalling tensorflow and python.

Full Traceback:

`I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set`

`I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA`

`To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.`

Virtual Environment Info:

-using a anaconda environment

-Python 3.7.9

-tensorflow 2.4.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I hid these warnings with:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

Note that this doesn't rebuild TensorFlow, but just hides the warning.

[Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u)

Comment: Where should we put these lines?!

Comment: @Dr.jacky at the top with your other imports

Comment: This doesn't address the question of "how to rebuild Tensorflow" but merely hides the warning. That may have been sufficient for what the OP wanted, but this should be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelMior that this does not solve the question on how to rebuild tensorflow

Answer (score 2):

To rebuild TensorFlow with compiler flags, you'll need to follow these steps:

1. **Install required dependencies**: You'll need to install the necessary software and libraries required to build TensorFlow. This includes a Python environment, the [Bazel build system](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases), and the Visual Studio Build Tools.
2. **Clone the [TensorFlow repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git)**: Clone the TensorFlow repository from GitHub to your local machine. This will give you access to the source code for TensorFlow.
3. **Configure the build**: Navigate to the TensorFlow repository you cloned in step 2 and run the configure.py script to configure the build. You can use the `--copt` flag to specify compiler flags during the configuration process.
4. **Build TensorFlow**: Use the Bazel build system to build TensorFlow. You can use the bazel build command to build the TensorFlow library and its dependencies.

Here's how I built TensorFlow with compiler flags on my Windows 10 machine:

```
# Clone the TensorFlow repository
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
 
# Navigate to the TensorFlow repository
cd tensorflow
 
# Configure the build
python configure.py --copt=-march=native
 
# Build TensorFlow
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Comment: Line 3 does not work anymore: `python configure.py --copt=-march=native`

`usage: configure.py [-h] [--workspace WORKSPACE]
configure.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --copt=-march=native`

Comment: according to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#optimizations it appears to be the default option now.