# ValueError: Found Shape in Keras Does Not Match Input Shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am using a tutorial on youtube. I took my own spin on it and although the code is essentially identical, I am getting an error message saying that the found shape does not match input shape

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 621, 17), found shape=(None, 17)
```

The code leading to this looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

datasetFull = pd.read_csv('College_Data.csv')
dataset = datasetFull.drop("Name", axis=1)

x = dataset.drop("Private", axis=1)

y = dataset["Private"]
y.replace('Yes', 1)
y.replace('No', 0)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

print(x_train.shape)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=x_train.shape, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

tf.reshape(x_train, [621, 17])

print(x_train.shape)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000)
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but I also get error messages like this that do not seem to actually stop the process.

```
This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

As you can see, I tried to `print` the shape of the input data before I take it as the input shape and before I submit it to `fit`

I also tried reshaping the input data right before submitting it to Keras with `tf.reshape(x_train, [621, 17])`

No matter what I did/do the same error always comes up:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 621, 17), found shape=(None, 17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix would be -

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], ), activation='sigmoid'))
```

The input shape must be an iterable and represent the number of independent variables, or in simple terms (**IN YOUR CASE**), the number of columns in *x_train*

**Improvements**

Rather than using -

```
y = dataset["Private"]
y.replace('Yes', 1)
y.replace('No', 0)
```

use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html), the added advantage would be simple, efficient and easy to convert from strings to numbers and vice versa. Also, I am not sure if you are actually converting the strings into numbers just by using `y.replace('Yes', 1)`. You are not setting the updated values back into *y*. According to me, it should have been `y = y.replace('Yes', 1)`. Same for replacing *"no"*

**Input and Output Shapes in MLP**

You can refer [this](https://mvschamanth.medium.com/decoding-the-input-shapes-and-output-shapes-of-multi-layered-perceptron-model-bf939b8579d8) to know more about input and output shapes of multilayer perceptrons.

**Warnings by Tensorflow**

Those other error messages are not relevant but some harmless warnings; you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227886/19060733) answer which explains it beautifully.

Comment: Did it not work ?