# Warning while using tensorflow : tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on

Tags: python, tensorflow

When using tensorflow, I get this warning

```
import tensorflow
 tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
```

I tried to change the environmental variable to 0 by set `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`. But still the issue persists.

Comment: How do you set the variable?

Comment: In order to take full advantage of Intel architecture and to extract maximum performance, the TensorFlow framework has been optimized using oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) primitives, a popular performance library for deep learning applications.  tensorflow-intel automatically set the TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=1. see https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-intel/

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '0'

import keras
```

It should work then without issues, at least for me it worked!

Answer (score 1):

**[Question 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77921357/warning-while-using-tensorflow-tensorflow-core-util-port-cc113-onednn-custom)**

`tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable` **TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0**

***Solutions:***

1.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '0'

import tensorflow as tf
```

2. 

```
    export TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0;
```

Here,
**TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0** should be above `import tensorflow as tf` as shown above code snippet.

**[Question 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068709/your-cpu-supports-instructions-that-this-tensorflow-binary-was-not-compiled-to-u)**

`To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.`

***Solutions:***

1.

```
    import os
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    
    import tensorflow as tf
```

2. 

`export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2`

Here,
**TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2** should be above `import tensorflow as tf` as shown above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this on Windows 11 by using the following method:

Environment Variables > Under System Variables I created a new variable with the name `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS` and set it's value to 0.

It solved the problem for me...